Faster VB6 / VBA class deallocation
VB6 / VBA is slow to deallocate class instances
VB* class instance deallocation becomes exponentially slower the more instances of that particular class there are.
Quick test. You will need:

Guido's excellent AccurateTimer library
a class module Class1 with no code
the following code in a standard .bas module

Run TestDeallocSpeed1 method.
Option Explicit

Sub TestDeallocSpeed1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim cInit As Currency
    Dim cDestroy As Currency
    Dim arr() As Class1
    Const alignR As Long = 14
    '
    Debug.Print AlignRight(alignR, "Instances", "Init (uS)", "Destroy (uS)")
    n = 3
    Do
        'Init
        ReDim arr(1 To n)
        cInit = AccurateTimerUs()
        For i = 1 To n
            Set arr(i) = New Class1
        Next i
        cInit = AccurateTimerUs() - cInit
        '
        'Destroy
        cDestroy = AccurateTimerUs()
        Erase arr
        cDestroy = AccurateTimerUs() - cDestroy
        '
        Debug.Print AlignRight(alignR, n, cInit, cDestroy)
        n = n * 1.2
    Loop Until n > 2 ^ 20
End Sub

Private Function AlignRight(ByVal size As Long, ParamArray args() As Variant) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim res As String
    Dim arg As String
    Dim lBuf As String: lBuf = Space$(size)
    '
    For Each v In args
        If IsNumeric(v) Then arg = Format$(v, "#,##0") Else arg = v
        arg = Right$(lBuf & arg, size)
        res = res & arg
    Next v
    AlignRight = res
End Function

The results will be printed to your Immediate window. Here are the results on my x64 VBA7 Windows, shown on a chart:

Creating almost 950,000 instances takes around 0.6 seconds while destroying them takes 185 seconds. Ridiculous.
Please note that this only applies to custom class modules. Destroying instances created in DLL references is fast, e.g. the native Collection from VBE7.DLL
Why is deallocation slow
Olaf Schmidt has done some investigation on this issue in the past. The following posts were really helpful:

Clearing-array-is-fast-in-VB5-but-very-slow-in-VB6
destroying-classes

Many thanks to Olaf. His work has put me on the right path to figure out why this is happening.
Apparently, each class instance holds a pointer to the previous instance immediately after the virtual table pointer i.e. at address ObjPtr(instance) + PTR_SIZE where PTR_SIZE is 4 (x32) or 8 (x64) bytes. We will explore the VB* class footprint later below to gain more clarity.
There are some assumptions being made in those posts. Here are the most important ones:

VB* must hold a pointer to the last created instance
when VB* destroys a class instance, it traverses all instances starting from the last created instance all the way to the first
the speed issue is probably caused by te registration / deregistration calls to IConnectionPoint interface while traversing the linked list of instance pointers
it's a possibility that the list of instance pointers is double-linked

After extensive testing, it turns out that only the first two assumptions are correct. I've discovered the following:

VB* does hold a pointer to the last instance
traversal indeed always goes from last instance to first
list of instance pointers is single-linked i.e. instances only "know" what the previous instance is but not the next
event deregistration does not affect speed
instances are often only partially destroyed, so that the class footprint memory space is reused
there is a second list of pointers but only for the partially destroyed instances. The pointers for this can be found at address ObjPtr(instance) i.e. where the vTable pointer was before termination. More details on this later below
each traversal can deallocate (free up memory) for none, one or more partially deallocated instances

In other words, the speed degradation cause is the following: while traversing, VB also deallocates instances that have nothing to do with the one currently being terminated. This is because instances can be partially destroyed. All the checks involved are presumably done for each instance being traversed thus exponentially taking longer. Demonstration further below.
Please note that throughout this explanation, the word Terminated refers to a Partial Deallocation.
VB* Class Footprint
We must first understand the layout of a class instance. Olaf's findings were really close:
Public Type VBClassHeader '64Bytes for a naked Class -> 16 32Bit Members
  pVTable As Long 
  pPreviousInstanceSameType As Long '<- here's the most interesting one 
  pUnkInstance As Long 'always denoting with 28Bytes Offs to our own ObjInstance-Ptr 
  pInstanceBaseClass As Long 'sidewards-allocation (extra memory) 
  pInstanceIConnectionPoint As Long 'sidewards-allocation (extra memory)
     YetToFindOut1 As Long 'usually at Zero 
     YetToFindOut2 As Long 'usually at Zero 
  pUnkVTable As Long 'the 7'th member after pVTable (= our 28Bytes Offs) 
  lRefCount As Long 
  lDataSourceBehaviourFlag As Long 
     YetToFindOut3 As Long 'usually at Zero 
  StateFlag As Long 'usually at &H100F, but at &H1C6E when terminating 
     YetToFindOut4 As Long 'usually at Zero 
'-> ...Class-private Vars will be inserted here, shifting the IClassModuleEvt-vTable down
  pVTableIClassModuleEvt As Long 
     YetToFindOut5 As Long 'usually at Zero 
     YetToFindOut6 As Long 'usually at Zero 
End Type

There are a few differences I found during testing:

pInstanceIConnectionPoint is in fact a pointer to an array of virtual function tables
pInstanceBaseClass is in fact pointing to the last virtual table in the array mentioned above
in between the class private vars and pVTableIClassModuleEvt there will be pointers to interfaces being implemented or interfaces created for vars WithEvents, if any
YetToFindOut5 is a pointer to where the Static class variables are stored i.e. the ones declared inside the class methods, if any

Let's update the names and make it x64 compatible. The members are prefixed with alphabet letters so that when viewed in the Locals window, while debugging, we can see them in the correct order.
Public Type VBClass
    a_VTableOrPrevTerm As LongPtr     'While Active, points to the class main virtual table (derived from IDispatch)
                                      'After termination, points to the previous terminated instance
    b_PreviousInstance As LongPtr     'Points to the previous created instance of the same class type. This can be a terminated instance
    c_IUnknownPtr As LongPtr          'Points to h_IUnknown virtual table i.e. offset 52 (x64) or 28 (x32) from instance pointer
    d_BaseClass As LongPtr            'Points to last vTable in array pointed by e_VBClassVTables i.e. e_VBClassVTables + PTR_SIZE * 6
    e_VBClassVTables As LongPtr       'Points to an array of virtual tables - see VBClassVTables struct below
    f_YetToFindOut1 As LongPtr        '0
    g_YetToFindOut2 As LongPtr        '0
    h_IUnknown As LongPtr             'Points to the class IUnknown virtual table
    i_RefCount As Long                'Instance reference count
    j_DataSourceBehaviourFlag As Long 'Seems to be 0 in VBA - don't have VB6 to test with
    k_YetToFindOut3 As Long           '0
    l_StateFlag As Long               'Initializing = &H1007 (while within Class_Initialize)
                                      'Active = &H100F,
                                      'Releasing = &H1057 (while within IUnknown::Release),
                                      'ReleasingLost = &H1867 (while within Release but state lost),
                                      'Terminating = &H1807 (while within Class_Terminate),
                                      'Terminated = &H1C6E (not destroyed)
    m_YetToFindOut4 As LongPtr        '0
    n_YetToFindOut5 As LongPtr        '0
    '
    'Class-private Variables will be inserted here, shifting the IClassModuleEvt-vTable down, if any
    '
    'Class implemented interfaces (virtual tables pointers) will be inserted here, if any
    'Interfaces created by VB automatically, when there are WithEvents variables declared, will be inserted here, if any
    '
    o_IClassModuleEvt As LongPtr      'Points to the class IClassModuleEvt virtual table
    p_StaticVars As LongPtr           'If any, a call to Win API like GlobalSize or LocalSize will return the byte size being used
    q_YetToFindOut6 As LongPtr        '0
End Type

Public Type VBClassVTables
    a_SomeVTable1 As LongPtr
    b_IConnectionPoint As LongPtr
    c_IConnectionPointCointainer As LongPtr
    d_SomeVTable2 As LongPtr
    e_SomeVTable3 As LongPtr
    f_IMarshall As LongPtr
    g_BaseClass As LongPtr
End Type

A quick test, run TestClassFootprint:
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Public Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
    #End If
#Else
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    #Else
        Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
    #End If
#End If
#If Win64 Then
    Public Const PTR_SIZE As Long = 8
    Public Const NULL_PTR As LongLong = 0^
#Else
    Public Const PTR_SIZE As Long = 4
    Public Const NULL_PTR As Long = 0&
#End If
#If VBA7 = 0 Then
    Public Enum LongPtr
        [_]
    End Enum
#End If

Public Function MemLongPtr(ByVal addr As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    CopyMemory MemLongPtr, ByVal addr, PTR_SIZE
End Function

Sub TestClassFootprint()
    Dim vc As VBClass
    Dim vct As VBClassVTables
    Dim temp As Class1
    Dim c As Class1
    '
    Set temp = New Class1
    Set c = New Class1
    '
    CopyMemory vc, ByVal ObjPtr(c), LenB(vc)
    CopyMemory vct, ByVal vc.e_VBClassVTables, LenB(vct)
    '
    Debug.Assert MemLongPtr(vc.d_BaseClass) = vct.g_BaseClass
    Debug.Assert vc.b_PreviousInstance = ObjPtr(temp)
    Debug.Assert MemLongPtr(vc.c_IUnknownPtr) = vc.h_IUnknown
    '
    Stop
End Sub

Looks like this:

VB* can partially destroy instances
These are, roughly, the steps that VB* takes when terminating a class instance:

IUnknown::Release is called as a result of:

user manually set the object variable to Nothing
object variable went out of scope
state was lost


if the reference count is bigger than 1, then it gets decreased and nothing else happens
if the reference count is 1 (i_RefCount), meaning it will be zero after decreasing, state is set to 'Terminated' (&H1C6E) at offset 76 (x64) / 44 (x32) bytes (l_StateFlag)
_Terminate is called on the IClassModuleEvt interface and so Class_Terminate is called, if present. However, if state was lost (e.g. End ran or Stop was pressed in the VBE) then Class_Terminate is not called
static variables are cleared - p_StaticVars points to where these are stored
internal variables are cleared, if not already cleared by bespoke code in Class_Terminate
pointers are cleared for (see class footprint in previous section):

a_VTableOrPrevTerm
d_BaseClass
e_VBClassVTables - the array pointed by this is also deallocated


the class footprint is never deallocated for the instance being terminated
VB traveses the list of instance pointers and might deallocate the class footprint for previously terminated instances, depending how many there are - again, these are held to be reused and presumably to avoid deallocate >> reallocate if unnecessary
VB will update the a_VTableOrPrevTerm to point to the previous terminated (but not deallocated) instance. If there are no previously terminated instances or if they were deallocated, then a_VTableOrPrevTerm will be set to zero / null ptr
VB will update the b_PreviousInstance pointers in case any previously terminated instances were deallocated

To test this, you must use Excel as it is important to see the results while code stops on the Stop lines. Keep the VBE and Excel windows side by side. Add this code to a standard module and run TestDealloc (press F5 key to jump to the next Stop):
Option Explicit

Sub TestDealloc()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Const n As Long = 30
    Dim c(1 To n) As Class1
    Dim ptrs(1 To n) As LongPtr
    '
    For i = 1 To n
        Set c(i) = New Class1
        ptrs(i) = ObjPtr(c(i))
        coll.Add i, CStr(ptrs(i))
    Next i
    coll.Add "vTblPtr", CStr(MemLongPtr(ObjPtr(c(1))))
    coll.Add "n/a", CStr(0)
    '
    WriteTraversal coll, ptrs(n) 'Start from last pointer
    Stop
    '
    For i = 1 To n
        If i Mod 7 = 0 Then
            Set c(i) = Nothing
            WriteTraversal coll, ptrs(n)
            Stop
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To n
        If i Mod 7 <> 0 Then
            Set c(i) = Nothing
            WriteTraversal coll, ptrs(n)
            Stop
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 4
        Set c(i) = New Class1
        WriteTraversal coll, ptrs(n)
        Stop
    Next i
    Erase c
    WriteTraversal coll, ptrs(n)
    Stop
End Sub

Sub WriteTraversal(ByVal coll As Collection, ByVal lastPtr As LongPtr)
    Dim res As New Collection
    Dim ptr As LongPtr: ptr = lastPtr
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    Do 'Traverse the linked list of instance pointers
        res.Add coll(CStr(ptr))
        res.Add coll(CStr(MemLongPtr(ptr))) 'vTbl or previously terminated
        ptr = MemLongPtr(ptr + PTR_SIZE) 'Previous instance
        res.Add coll(CStr(ptr))
    Loop Until ptr = NULL_PTR
    '
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Const c As Long = 3
    Dim r As Long: r = res.Count / c
    Dim arr() As Variant: ReDim arr(1 To r, 1 To c)
    '
    i = r
    For Each v In res
        j = j + 1
        arr(i, j) = v
        If j = c Then
            j = 0
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next v
    '
    With Range("A1")
        .Resize(1, 3).Value2 = Array("Instance #" _
                                   , "VTbl or prevTerminated" _
                                   , "Prev instance")
        With .Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1, c).Value2 = Empty
            .Resize(r, c).Value2 = arr
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Please note that I chose to use the index of the instance (in the creation order) instead of using pointers, to make it easier to follow what is going on.
The above code illustrates how previously terminated instances are reused and how deallocation works. Here's a gif:

Pelase note that I did not share code used to test and prove some of the points mentioned here (e.g. how e_VBClassVTables is deallocated or how l_StateFlag is changed). This is because it would bloat this question and it's irrelevant to the following section.
The above code/gif only runs a simple demonstation but in reality, while instances are terminated and reused, the order of those pointers can point in both directions e.g. instance 17 points to instance 16 at PTR_SIZE offset while pointing to instance 50 at zero offset because both 17 and 50 are partially deallocated.
Overcome VB design - Faster Instance Deallocation
My goal was to make VBA-FastDictionary faster, which is a must for working with JSON. JSON that took 8 seconds to parse was taking hundreds of seconds to deallocate, but with this and eventually this, the deallocation is now under a second.
The problem with VBA7 is that it has a massive API overhead - see this Code Review question. If we want to keep all code inside the relevant class, then we must copy memory using something native. I am using fake arrays which I call memory accesors but we could also use fake Variant ByRef (see VBA-MemoryTools for both approaches).
For now, this is the code needed to fix the problem for our example Class1 but see the next section for other thoughts and ideas. Please note we need the global instance i.e. Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True. So, place the below code in a Class1.cls text file and then import that file:
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
    #End If
#Else 'Windows
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    #Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
    #End If
#End If
#If VBA7 = 0 Then
    Private Enum LongPtr
        [_]
    End Enum
#End If

#Const Windows = (Mac = 0)
#Const x64 = Win64
    
Private Enum InternalConstants 'Hides constants from Locals window
#If x64 Then
    ptrSize = 8
#Else
    ptrSize = 4
#End If
    prevOffset = ptrSize 'Previous instance pointer immediately after vTable
End Enum

Private Type SAFEARRAYBOUND
    cElements As Long
    lLbound As Long
End Type
Private Type SAFEARRAY_1D
    cDims As Integer
    fFeatures As Integer
    cbElements As Long
    cLocks As Long
    pvData As LongPtr
    rgsabound0 As SAFEARRAYBOUND
End Type
             
'Data shared across all class instances
Private Type Globals
    saP As SAFEARRAY_1D
    d As Double 'A safe pointer
    dPtr As LongPtr
    lastInstancePtr As LongPtr
    lastTerminatedPtr As LongPtr
    lastTerminatedNextPtr As LongPtr
    nextPtrOffset As LongPtr
    defPtrOffset As LongPtr
End Type

'These will link into the default (Predeclared) instance of this class
Private Type MemoryAccessors
    Common() As Globals
    RPtr() As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type DeallocVars
    ThisPtr As LongPtr
    NextClassPtr As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type ClassVariables
    DefInstance As Class1 'Avoids deallocation of default (Predeclared) instance
    Dealloc As DeallocVars
End Type

'Class members
Private Vars As ClassVariables
Private Mem As MemoryAccessors

Private Sub InitSafeArray(ByRef sa As SAFEARRAY_1D, ByVal elemSize As Long)
    Const FADF_AUTO As Long = &H1
    Const FADF_FIXEDSIZE As Long = &H10
    Const FADF_COMBINED As Long = FADF_AUTO Or FADF_FIXEDSIZE
    With sa
        .cDims = 1
        .fFeatures = FADF_COMBINED
        .cbElements = elemSize
        .cLocks = 1
    End With
End Sub

'To avoid API calls overhead memory accessors are cached in the default instance
'   (Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True)
Friend Sub InitStructs(ByRef v As ClassVariables _
                     , ByRef m As MemoryAccessors)
    #If x64 Then
        Const nullPtr As LongLong = 0^
    #Else
        Const nullPtr As Long = 0&
    #End If
    Static h As Globals
    Static saH As SAFEARRAY_1D
    Static saPtrs(0 To 1) As LongPtr
    Dim temp As Object
    '
    If Not Vars.DefInstance Is Nothing Then
        Vars.DefInstance.InitStructs v, m
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    If saH.cDims = 0 Then
        h.nextPtrOffset = VarPtr(Vars.Dealloc.NextClassPtr) - Vars.Dealloc.ThisPtr
        h.defPtrOffset = VarPtr(Vars.DefInstance) - Vars.Dealloc.ThisPtr
        '
        saPtrs(0) = VarPtr(saH)
        saPtrs(1) = VarPtr(h.saP)
        '
        InitSafeArray saH, LenB(h)
        InitSafeArray h.saP, ptrSize
        '
        saH.pvData = VarPtr(h)
        h.dPtr = VarPtr(h.d)
        h.saP.pvData = h.dPtr
        '
        saH.rgsabound0.cElements = 1
        h.saP.rgsabound0.cElements = 1
        '
        'The only API call
        CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(Mem) + ptrSize, saPtrs(1), ptrSize
    End If
    '
    'Avoid deallocation of Global Instance
    If v.Dealloc.ThisPtr <> Vars.Dealloc.ThisPtr Then Set v.DefInstance = Me
    '
    'Init memory accesors for each instance
    h.saP.pvData = VarPtr(m)
    Mem.RPtr(0) = saPtrs(0)
    h.saP.pvData = h.saP.pvData + ptrSize
    Mem.RPtr(0) = saPtrs(1)
    '
    'Read previous instance pointer
    h.saP.pvData = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr + prevOffset
    '
    Dim prevPtr As LongPtr: prevPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
    Dim tempPtr As LongPtr
    '
    If prevPtr = nullPtr Then 'Can only be def instance
        h.lastInstancePtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
        h.saP.pvData = h.dPtr
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    'In case user modified the global instance e.g. Set Class1 = Nothing
    If v.DefInstance Is Nothing Then
        Do
            h.saP.pvData = prevPtr + h.defPtrOffset
            tempPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
            If tempPtr Then Exit Do
            '
            h.saP.pvData = prevPtr + prevOffset
            If Mem.RPtr(0) = nullPtr Then
                h.saP.pvData = prevPtr + h.nextPtrOffset
                If Mem.RPtr(0) Then tempPtr = prevPtr
                Exit Do
            End If
            prevPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
        Loop
        If (tempPtr <> nullPtr) And (tempPtr <> Vars.Dealloc.ThisPtr) Then
            'Link to the 'real' def instance
            h.saP.pvData = VarPtr(temp)
            Mem.RPtr(0) = tempPtr 'Unmanaged - ref count not increased
            Set Vars.DefInstance = temp
            Mem.RPtr(0) = nullPtr 'Ref count not decreased
            '
            Vars.DefInstance.InitStructs Vars, Mem
            With Mem.Common(0)
                .saP.pvData = .lastTerminatedPtr + prevOffset
                If Mem.RPtr(0) = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr Then
                    'Previous instance is currently initializing and it is
                    '   definitely reusing previously terminated memory
                    v.Dealloc.NextClassPtr = .lastTerminatedPtr
                    .saP.pvData = .lastTerminatedPtr + .nextPtrOffset
                    Mem.RPtr(0) = .lastTerminatedNextPtr
                    .lastTerminatedNextPtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
                    .saP.pvData = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr + prevOffset
                    .lastTerminatedPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
                End If
                .saP.pvData = .dPtr
            End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    '
    If v.Dealloc.ThisPtr = h.lastTerminatedPtr Then
        'Reusing previously terminated memory
        v.Dealloc.NextClassPtr = h.lastTerminatedNextPtr
        h.lastTerminatedPtr = prevPtr
        h.lastTerminatedNextPtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
    Else
        If prevPtr = h.lastInstancePtr Then
            h.lastInstancePtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
        Else 'The previous instance could be initializing
            h.saP.pvData = prevPtr + prevOffset
            If Mem.RPtr(0) = h.lastInstancePtr Then
                h.lastInstancePtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
            End If
        End If
    End If
    h.saP.pvData = prevPtr + h.nextPtrOffset
    Mem.RPtr(0) = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
    '
    h.saP.pvData = h.dPtr
End Sub

'Only initialize memory manipulation structs
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Vars.Dealloc.ThisPtr = ObjPtr(Me)
    Class1.InitStructs Vars, Mem
End Sub

'Postpones termination to a later stage where we have full control over how VBA
'   traverses the linked list of all class instances
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'Deallocate internal variables here e.g. other Class1 instances
    '...
    '...
    '
    'Cache this instance inside the global instance and destroy later
    Vars.DefInstance.DelayTermination Me, Vars
    Set Vars.DefInstance = Nothing
End Sub

'When VB* terminates a class instance, it traverses all instances starting from
'   the last created instance all the way to the first. On itself this would be
'   fast but unfortunately VB also makes checks and can reclaim memory that is
'   unrelated to the instance being terminated. So, this traversal becomes
'   exponentially slower the more instances there are - O(n^2)
'This method 'tricks' VB into traversing only a handful of instances thus making
'   the whole termination process linear - O(n)
Friend Sub DelayTermination(ByRef instanceToDelay As Class1 _
                          , ByRef v As ClassVariables)
    #If x64 Then
        Const nullPtr As LongLong = 0^
    #Else
        Const nullPtr As Long = 0&
    #End If
    Static pendingClass As Class1
    Static pendingPtr As LongPtr
    Static lastClass As Class1
    Static lastClassPtr As LongPtr
    Dim prevPtr As LongPtr
    Dim followPtr As LongPtr
    Dim secondLastPtr As LongPtr
    Dim tempClass As Class1
    '
    If pendingClass Is Nothing Then
        Set pendingClass = instanceToDelay
        pendingPtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Mem.Common(0)
        If pendingPtr = .lastInstancePtr Then
            'We force keep the last instance active to avoid extra logic
            If lastClass Is Nothing Then
                Set lastClass = pendingClass
                lastClassPtr = pendingPtr
                Set pendingClass = instanceToDelay
                pendingPtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
                Exit Sub
            End If
            '
            Set tempClass = lastClass
            Set lastClass = pendingClass
            Set pendingClass = tempClass
            Set tempClass = Nothing
            pendingPtr = lastClassPtr
            lastClassPtr = .lastInstancePtr
        End If
        '
        If .lastTerminatedPtr = nullPtr Then
            .lastTerminatedPtr = Vars.Dealloc.ThisPtr 'Use Def instance
        End If
        '
        .saP.pvData = pendingPtr + prevOffset
        prevPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
        '
        If prevPtr = .lastTerminatedPtr Then
            .saP.pvData = pendingPtr + .nextPtrOffset
            followPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
        Else 'Insert after last terminated
            Mem.RPtr(0) = .lastTerminatedPtr
            .saP.pvData = .lastTerminatedPtr + .nextPtrOffset
            '
            Dim tempPtr As LongPtr: tempPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
            Mem.RPtr(0) = pendingPtr
            '
            .saP.pvData = tempPtr + prevOffset
            Mem.RPtr(0) = pendingPtr
            '
            .saP.pvData = pendingPtr + .nextPtrOffset
            followPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
            Mem.RPtr(0) = tempPtr
            '
            If prevPtr <> nullPtr Then 'Not first ever instance
                .saP.pvData = prevPtr + .nextPtrOffset
                Mem.RPtr(0) = followPtr
            End If
            '
            .saP.pvData = followPtr + prevOffset
            Mem.RPtr(0) = prevPtr
            followPtr = tempPtr
        End If
        '
        'Make VB 'believe' that trailing instance is the last instance
        '   so that a shorter list is traversed when we terminate 'pending'
        .saP.pvData = .lastInstancePtr + prevOffset
        secondLastPtr = Mem.RPtr(0)
        Mem.RPtr(0) = pendingPtr
        '
        Set pendingClass = Nothing 'Traverse short list and deallocate as needed
        '
        Mem.RPtr(0) = secondLastPtr 'Restore to long list
        '
        .saP.pvData = pendingPtr + prevOffset
        If .lastTerminatedPtr <> Mem.RPtr(0) Then 'Memory was reclaimed
            .saP.pvData = Mem.RPtr(0) + .nextPtrOffset
            Mem.RPtr(0) = pendingPtr
        End If
        .lastTerminatedPtr = pendingPtr
        .lastTerminatedNextPtr = followPtr
        .saP.pvData = .dPtr
        '
        Set pendingClass = instanceToDelay
        pendingPtr = v.Dealloc.ThisPtr
    End With
End Sub

Now run again the TestDeallocSpeed1 method that we initially ran on Class1 when it had no code. This is the new result:

So, destroying 950,000 instances used to take 185 seconds but it is now done in 0.67 seconds. This is how things should be - destroy should be faster than create.
Other approaches and ideas
Needless to say, reaching the above result took literally months and I explored and implemented several approaches. I won't go into details on them but I will share some thoughts on the current approach and some ideas to expand the solution.
I chose to implement all code inside the relevant class as I wanted to have a self-contained solution, which was always the goal for a single-class library like VBA-FastDictionary. You probably realized that the Class1 solution above is just a stripped down version of the dictionary class.
However, all this could be done using a standard .bas module that could handle all the memory manipulation to overcome the API overhead and it could be written to support multiple classes. For example, all classes would pass themselves to a global method which would then keep track of the necessary pointers per each class type. The code would be quite complicated, but definitely doable. While this would be a great fit-all solution it would introduce a necessary dependency on that standard module.
Alternatively, we could have the memory manipulation inside a standard module while still keeping track of the pointers inside each class. Easier to implement but still with dependency.
Current approach
For those who don't have the time to understand what the code does. Here are the main ideas:

we keep track of the next instance pointer in each instance while we let VB* keep track of the previous instance
we keep track of the last instance ever created which VB also does. This is slightly tricky because the user can terminate the global instance and so we have to maintain a default instance that coordinates everything and stores such "global" pointers
we never deallocate the last instance. This greatly simplifies the logic needed and is much faster. This implies that we always have at least 2 active instances: the default and the last. These will only be deallocated when state is lost / application quits
when the Class_Terminate method is called, we simply store the instance as pending so that we get outside the scope of Class_Terminate. In other words, we delay termination. While this is going on, we can terminate the previously pending instance, if any
when we terminate a pending instance, we make sure to trick VB* into traversing a shorter list of instances. To do that, we make sure we insert the pending instance immediately after the previously terminated (or the default one). This could require up to 6 pointer swaps to make sure we maintain our now double-linked list. Once inserted, we link the very last created instance directly to our pending instance, meaning VB* will skip traversing anything in between. At this step, VB* might deallocate one or more previously terminated instances (which we've maintained in order by doing the swaps) but will never deallocate the one pending
once terminated, we restore the list to it's full length so that VB can properly deallocate in case of state loss

Question
Can this approach be improved?
Any other feedback or suggestions are welcome.

Love this question, we have seem resident VB magicians, I hope you will get a great review.

This is a ridiculous problem. Well done for solving it :D
